# Como escapar aspas de uma chave do json no Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tenho uma função que recebe JSON's, acontece que é possivel o usuario colocar do seguinte modo:

**Normal**:

```
'[{"nome":"João Carlos"}, {"nome":"Maria Silva"}]'
```

**Problema**:

```
'[{"nome":"João - "Carlos" - "}, {"nome":"Maria Silva"}]'
```

Reparem que é possivel o usuario colocar aspas duplas ou simples no campo  **nome**, como eu poderia escapar essas aspas?

Eu utilizo a função `JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS` para separar em linhas cada JSON.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    json_array_elements('[{"nome":"João - "Carlos" - "}, {"nome":"Maria Silva"}]')
```

Comment: já tentou usando o scape ou aspas duplas repetidas? tipo `json_array_elements('[{"nome":"João - \"Carlos\" - "}, {"nome":"Maria Silva"}]')` ou `json_array_elements('[{"nome":"João - ""Carlos"" - "}, {"nome":"Maria Silva"}]')`

Comment: @AdrianoGomes Até pensei, mas eu como eu poderia colocar essas barras invertidas?

Comment: vc está usando alguma linguagem de programação para executar o script sql?

Comment: Node.JS para executar a função do postgresql que recebe o JSON e insere em tabela.

Comment: Ao invés de usar a função json_array_elements e usar apenas o node para criar essa lista é uma opção?

Comment: O problema é que o formato do json está inválido, você precisa informar a barra invertida quando existe aspas duplas numa string, como o @AdrianoGomes sugeriu. Se não fizer isso você não vai conseguir fazer o parse. Uma alternativa seria tratar pelo node os dados informados pelo usuário, acrescentando as barras.

Comment: No node só consegui fazer a usando ao invés de uma barra invertida, duas, ficando dessa forma: `var str = '[{"nome":"João - \\"Carlos\\" - "}, {"nome":"Maria Silva"}]';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(obj); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há nada de errado na sua função!

Este dado em formato `JSON` que você está tentando processar está *malformado*, veja bem:

```
'[{"nome":"João - "Carlos" - "}, {"nome":"Maria Silva"}]'
```

Repare que não há como diferenciar as aspas que devem ser escapadas das que não devem ser!

O problema está fora do escopo da sua função.

O chamador (*caller*) da sua função precisa ter o cuidado de passar um `JSON` válido como argumento ao chamá-la.

Talvez isso possa ajudar: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-ESCAPE-STRING